# Access UITextField's text content nested in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm trying to **access the content of UITextFields** that's nested in a UITableView when a "save" button is pressed.

However, debugging (as shown further below) shows that **I can access anything about the texfield except its text**...

Whatever I type inside it before pressing the button has no impact...

I feel like I should use the UITextField Delegate but don't understand neither **why** nor **how**...

This is the code I'm using:

```
@IBAction func saveNewGuestButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let entity : NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Guest", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)!
    // Initialize Record
    let record : Guest = Guest(entity:entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext)
    // Populate Record
    for i in 0..<3
    {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
        let cell = tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! newGuestProtoCell
        if i==0
        {
            record.guestFirst = cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField.text
            println("indexPath :\(indexPath), recorded : \(record.guestFirst) and TextField : \(cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField.text) + \(cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField). test : \(cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField.defaultTextAttributes) and \(cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField.attributedText) and \(cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField.placeholder) and \(cell.newGuestFirstNameTextField.tag)")
        }
        if i==1
        {
            record.guestLast = cell.newGuestLastNameTextField.text

            println("indexPath :\(indexPath), recorded Last : \(record.guestLast), recorded first : \(record.guestFirst) and textfield : \(cell.newGuestLastNameTextField.text)")
            //newGuest["lastName"] = cell.newGuestLastNameTextField.text
        }
        if i==2 && guestImage != nil
        {

            record.guestImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(guestImage) as NSData
            println("indexPath :\(indexPath), recorded image: \(record.guestImage.superclass) and UIImageView's image : \(cell.guestImageIV.image)")
        }
    }
```

The console prints the following, which proves that the problems is not in my tableview, my "for" loop to access it nor the textfield itself (or it's "*outlet*") :

> **indexPath :** {length = 2, path = 0 -
>   0}, **recorded :**  **and TextField :  +** >. **test :**
>   [NSParagraphStyle: Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0,
>   ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 4, Tabs (
>       28L,
>       56L,
>       84L,
>       112L,
>       140L,
>       168L,
>       196L,
>       224L,
>       252L,
>       280L,
>       308L,
>       336L ), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0,
>   HeaderLevel 0, NSShadow: NSShadow {0, -1} color = {(null)}, NSFont:
>    font-family:
>   ".HelveticaNeueInterface-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style:
>   normal; font-size: 14.00pt, NSColor: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1]
>   and Optional() and Optional("First Name") and 0 indexPath
>   : {length = 2, path = 0 - 1},
>   recorded Last : , recorded first :  and textfield :  indexPath
>   : {length = 2, path = 0 - 2},
>   recorded image: Optional(NSMutableData) and UIImageView's image :
>   Optional( size {1500, 1001} orientation 0
>   scale 1.000000)

Answer (score 0):

By reading your code, you are doing things wrong:

```
let cell = tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! newGuestProtoCell
```

The cellForRowAtIndexPath is used to prepare the view to show it. So it should clear what you typed in, and fill in the content for the correct record. (The record at indexpath). Then you should get a view with textview's text as null.

Regard on how to get the values out, you can setup the delegate UITextFieldDelegate in the exact method. tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath).